# How to TeX this glyph?

Tags: symbols

It is `0x20` in this table.

http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsmath/symbols/cmr10.html

According to amsfonts and the structure of `.afm` files (See Chapter 8 of https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5004.AFM_Spec.pdf) its name should be "suppress".

http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/fonts/amsfonts/afm/cmr10.afm

`C 32 ; WX 277 ; N suppress ; B 27 280 262 392 ;`

I struggle to find a glyph in any table of PostScript language character names with that name. Could anyone please help me find some `TeX` code other than ones that use the encoding itself such as `\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\char"20`. Really thanks!

Comment: The only usage I can find for this glyph is in the the commands `\l` and `\L` to typeset the Polish letter ł/Ł.

Comment: As noted by @siracusa, this is a TeX-specific "diacritic" used to produce the Polish suppressed ell.  When TeX was developed, there was not enough memory available to include these letters in the fonts.  Unicode does not recognize or require such a mechanism to identify these letters.  You will almost certainly not find such a mark in any font not specifically created for the original TeX.

Comment: It's sometimes known as “lslashslash“, as far as I remember, but I don't think it has an official Postscript name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear what kind of answer you want, the character is the bar intended for a `\l`  (U+0142).

It is not given any real name, the definition of `\l` in OT1 encoding is

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\l}{OT1}
   {\hmode@bgroup\@xxxii l\egroup}
```

So the TeX code for the bar is`\@xxxii` which is defined by

```
\chardef\@xxxii=32
```

so essentially the same as the `\char"20` you already show in the question.